# how to send report to Acralyzer manual

Tags: android, android-studio, crash-reports, acra, acralyzer

I am using Acralyzer for reporting of errors (Crash reports)
Now I want to manually send a Custom report to Acra.
But do not know , how to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
try 
{
    // some code
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
}
```